# Django filter with replace

Tags: django, postgresql, filtering

Let's say I have the following model which have a method variants():

```
class Example(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def variants(self):
        return Example.objects.filter(text=remove('xy', self.text))
```

The idea is to get all objects where texts are the same after certain characters are removed from the text. For example, if self.text is 'axxyy', it should match with the object which have text 'a'. Function remove() doesn't touch to the database, it returns a new string which have given characters removed. This works fine.

However, I have a need to perform the same operation on both sides of the comparison, so that variants() would behave like following:

```
    def variants(self):
        return Example.objects.filter(remove('xy', text)=remove('xy', self.text))
```

In that case, if self.txt is 'axxyy' it should match with 'a', 'ax, 'axx', 'xayy', etc. but shouldn't match with 'aa' for example, since 'a' != 'aa' after removals. Once again, I don't want to remove 'xy' from the database, only for the comparison.

I could do this with Python, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this on database level? I've been reading docs about Func() expressions, for example Replace, but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Annotate using django's Replace function, then filter on that annotation.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Replace
from django.db.models import Value
...

    def variants(self):
        return Example.objects.annotate(
            removed_x=Replace('text', Value('x'), Value('')),
            removed_xy=Replace('removed_x', Value('y'), Value('')),
        ).filter(
            removed_xy=self.text.replace('x' , '').replace('y', '')
        )
```

Note that the replacement argument `Value('')` is optional, since that's actually `Replace()`'s default, but it's better explicit in the example.

This doesn't scale well as the number of characters grows, but there may be better solutions using regex if your DB supports that (Postgres)

Comment: This works indeed, and it's a great solution if you have only one or two strings to replace. I have to remove at least five characters so it gets a little complicated. I was looking for something like Replace('text', Value('xyzw'), Value('')) for the other side to keep it simpler.

Anyway, even though this exact solution isn't optimal for me, it's probably good solution for other similar use cases and your answer also gave me an idea how to proceed. I'm using Postgres so regex is probably the way to go. I'll accept this answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering to my own question as I was able to make this work with the help of Tim Nyborg's answer. I'm not sure if this is the most beautiful and efficient way to do this, but it seems to work very fast with the amount of data I'm dealing and it scales up well for growing number of replacement patterns. This solution works only with the Postgres as it uses 'regexp_replace' for replaces.

Here is the example implementation:

```
def variants(self):
    patterns = [
        ('[xyz️w]', ''),
        ('[\u00A0]', ' '),
        # etc.
    ]

    # Replace characters in self.text
    text_i = self.text
    for old, new in patterns:
        text_i = re.sub(old, new, text_i)

    # Replace the same characters in all other objects
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    for i, value in enumerate(patterns):
        old, new = value
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            **{f'text_{i}': Func(F(f'text_{i - 1}' if i > 0 else 'text'),
                                 Value(old), Value(new), Value('g'),
                                 function='regexp_replace')})
    else:
        # Filter all where replaced texts are the same
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{f'text_{i}': text_i}).exclude(pk=self.pk)

    return queryset
```

Regex itself solves most of the problems as it's possible to replace multiple characters at once, but my patterns are rather complicated so I split them to list and annotated with dynamically built field names.

Having said that, I'm not 100% yet if I actually keep using this solution or rather add one more field to the model which stores to value of 'text_i' (replacements already done) for each object and then just do like this:

```
def variants(self):
    return Example.objects.filter(text_i=self.text_i).exclude(pk=self.pk)
```

I just have to consider whether 'text_i' is stable enough for my purpose so that I don't have to keep updating them constantly after the initial creation.